# Fragment already added with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

This is an odd error which I'm battling with at the moment.

I have an activity that displays a search fragment once it has completed initialisation. The search fragment contains a listview to display the results and that listview is inside a SwipeRefreshLayout so that the user can refresh the search results.

If the user selects an item from the list the search fragment is removed and the parent activity is displayed (it has other fragments). The user can choose to open the search fragment and refresh the results if they wish.

The behaviour I have is that if they use the swipe refresh when the fragment is first opened it works as expected. However, if they dismiss the search fragment and then open it again and then swipe down for refresh I get the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added` exception thrown for the search fragment.

The code to introduce the search fragment the first time is:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void empty) {
    dismissSearchProgress();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
        setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, 0, 0, R.animator.slide_out_left).
        add(R.id.main_vwContent, mWoSearchFragment).commit();
}
```

The second time the code is introduced via a swipe action on the screen:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    if (swipeInRange) {
        /* do some other stuff */
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, 0, 0, R.animator.slide_out_left).add(R.id.main_vwContent, mWoSearchFragment).commit();
    }
    break;
```

There are no errors thrown in the second instance unless they swipe down to refresh. The error is thrown before the onRefresh event fires.

Anyone have any ideas? Not sure what code is attempting to add the search fragment again as the exception does not have any of my code in the stack trace and the debugger isn't catching anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's amazing what writing up a problem will do for you. The issue was that to open the fragment the user has to swipe from a particular screen location. So on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` we check to see if they have started within the target area and set a flag. Then on 'MotionEvent.ACTION_UP' the fragment is added. However, in the case of a SwipeRefreshLayout it intercepts the 'MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN' event however it pushes the 'MotionEvent.ACTION_UP' up the stack.

So in my case, the flag was still set to true as the last action taken before the refresh was to swipe to add the fragment.

The fix was to ensure that the flag was reset to false when the search fragment was added.